# Formatting json data to work in Flot

Tags: php, javascript, json, flot

Is there anyway to convert this json data:

```
[

    {
        "year":"1999",
        "value":"3.0"
    },
    {
        "year":"2008",
        "value":"0.9"
    }

]
```

to like this:

```
{
    "data": [[1999, 3.0], [2008, 0.9]]
}
```

Check type of values ("3.0" and 3.0, string and integer).

I am having hard time to figure this out, or is it even possible.

This is how I get the json data:
I have "data" table in my database where are "year" and "value" columns, I get them from database like:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
        $rows = array();
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
        $encodedJson = json_encode($rows);

$encodedJson = json_encode($rows);
print $encodedJson;
```

I am trying to create a graph from my data, and json data must be formated properly to work in [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).
All help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible.

Comment: Probably simpler to build the data structure as you want it in php using a hash. That way json_encode() will output the structure properly.

Comment: where do you want to achieve this? in php or javascript

Comment: PHP would be preferable

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could *map* your array of objects into an multidimensional array:

```
var mapped = originalData.map(function (obj) {
  return [ parseInt(obj.year, 10), parseFloat(obj.value) ];
});

var newData = {
  data: mapped
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution

```
  var a = [

        {
            "year":"1999",
            "value":"3.0"
        },
        {
            "year":"2008",
            "value":"0.9"
        }

    ];

    var b = [];
    $.each(a, function(_index, _item){
        var c = [_item["year"], _item["value"]];
        b.push(c);
    });

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.
PHP:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
 $rows = $sql->results_array();
$return_args = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
  $tmp[0] = $row['year'];
  $tmp[1] = $row['value'];
  array_push($return_args,$tmp);
}

 $encodedJson = json_encode($return_args);

 print $encodedJson;
```